# Division between the terms of two sequences result in an integer

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series

This is a followup to an earlier question I had. I am more of a software developer than I am a math person so please bear with me.

If I have 2 sequences (these are two programming arrays in practice):

$$a = {1000,994,988....n}$$

$$b = {3, 13, 23....n}$$

I want to divide the nth term in sequence A by the nth term in sequence B and see if the result is an integer (not an irrational number). Is there a more efficient way to do this without manually going through each term in both sequences and dividing them one by one? I guess this is expression I am looking for:

$$\frac{an - 6}{bn + 10} = Integer$$

So in this example, it would go :

$$\frac{1000 }{3} \ne Integer$$
$$\frac{994 }{13} \ne Integer$$
.....and so on. I am not interested in which terms or the values of the terms, what I am interested is simply only do any of the terms from sequence A divided by the same term in sequence B result in an integer.

Comment: I think it ultimately depends on the sequences you're working with in practice. For instance, you assume each sequence here in linear in $n$ - that is, each element has the form $an+b$ for $a,b$ constant. But things suddenly become a lot tougher in general analysis if you have polynomial patterns or something else. So I guess the pertinent question that I should have asked before is this -- what kind of sequences are you working with?

Comment: @EeveeTrainer Please excuse my mathematical illiteracy, but I will try to answer the best I can. Sequence A's first term will always be larger than Sequence B's first term. Sequence A will always be decreasing and Sequence B will always be increasing. The last term in Sequence A will always have to be >0 and the first term in Sequence B will always be >0. Both sequences will have the same number of terms. Please let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: Basically what I'm asking is that if each sequence's terms can be assumed to have the form $an+b$, as opposed to, say, $n^2+2n+5$ or $e^{5n}$ or something like that.

Comment: Yes, the sequences will only be in the form of an+b. So basically both sequences will start at some integer number and be added/subtracted by another integer number.

Comment: If you meant that the two sequences are arithmetic sequences, then you can just say so.  

$ a_n = a_0 + \delta_1 n $

$ b_n = b_0 + \delta_2 n $

And now you're asking how to determine if/when $ a_n $ is divisible by $ b_n $.  By the way, your use of the word "irrational" was incorrect in your original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation can be written

$$\frac{1000-6n}{3+10n}=k\in\mathbb N.$$

We can rearrange it as

$$(5k+3)(10n+3)=5009.$$

As $5009$ is a prime number, no solution exists.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply! Sorry, I am not very good at math, could you please explain how you rearranged the first equation to be the second equation?

Comment: @user2924127: expand both.

Comment: Sorry I am still confused when you say expand both. If I expand I get 50kn + 30n + 15k +9.

Comment: @user2924127: $9$ ?

Comment: I am very limited in my math knowledge so my definition of expanding is going (5k*10n) + (5k*3) + (3*10n) + (3*3)

Comment: @user2924127: ok, but there's the $5009$ in the RHS.

Comment: So are you saying to subtract the 9 from the LHS and the RHS to get 50kn + 30n + 15k = 5000? If so, I am not sure what this does exactly?

Comment: @user2924127: compare to the other equation.

Comment: ahhh so I think I kind of understand. $50kn + 15k +30n = 5000$ is equal to $10kn + 3k + 6n = 1000$ which is equal to $10kn + 3k = 1000 - 6n$. This is where I am now stuck, how do I get $3+10n$ as the divisor on the bottom?

Comment: @user2924127: just divide by $10n+3$ !

Comment: but if I divide by that wouldn't I get $k+k$ on the LHS? Shouldn't it just be one k?

Comment: @user2924127: no.

Comment: But wouldn't the equation $\frac{10kn+3k}{10n + 3}$ be left with k from the $10kn$ and the k from the $3k$?

Comment: @user2924127: obvioulsy, that's what we want.

Comment: Sorry still confused, so wouldn't that leave k + k? Don't we want to isolate to only have one k on the LHS?

Comment: I have tried for a bit now but cannot understand how you went from 1000−6n3+10n=k∈N. to (5k+3)(10n+3)=5009. May you please show the steps on how you did this?

Answer (score 0):

We adopt the notation $ a_n = a_0 + \delta_1 n $ and $ b_n = b_0 + \delta_2 n $.  We are now trying to solve a diophantine equation in the two variables $ n $ and $ k $,
$$
a_0 + \delta_1 n = k (b_0 + \delta_2 n)
$$
Move stuff around:
$$
\delta_2 n k + b_0 k - \delta_1 n - a_0 = 0
$$
This is a quadratic diophantine equation.  Apparently there are algorithms to solve these readily available, see https://mathoverflow.net/a/143427/109688

Comment: Please excuse my lack of knowledge, this is pretty advanced for me. So using the example above $a_o$ would refer to 1000 and $b_0$ would be 3? And then would $S_1n$ be equal to -6 and $S_2n$ be equal to 10? And what would the value of $k$ be?

Comment: @user2924127 Yes $ a_0 = 1000 $, $ b_0 = 3 $.  $ \delta_1 = -6 $, $ \delta_2 = 10 $.  Now, as I said, $ n $ and $ k $ are the variables you are solving for.  $ k $ you can "throw away" (you don't care about it).  $ n $ is what you care about in the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since  $\dfrac{1000-6n}{3+10n}=k$ represents the equation of an hyperbola, we can solve   for example $$|k|\ge 10\iff-11\lt n\lt9$$ and verify that for the values $n=-10,-9,\cdots,7,8$ we have no solution. Then there are no solutions. **But much better would be take a look at the very nice answer above gives by Yves Daoust.**